# Multiple threads sending over one socket simultaneously?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have two python programs. Program 1 displays videos in a grid with multiple controls on it, and Program 2 performs manipulations to the images and sends it back depending on the control pressed in Program 1.

Each video in the grid is running in its own thread, and each video has a thread in Program 2 for sending results back.

I'm running this on the same machine though and I was unable to get multiple socket connections working to and from the same address (localhost). If there's a way of doing that - please stop reading and tell me how!

I currently have one socket sitting independent of all of my video threads in Program 1, and in Program 2 I have multiple threads sending data to the one socket in an array with a flag for which video the data is for. The problem is when I have multiple threads sending data at the same time it seems to scramble things and stop working. Any tips on how I can achieve this?

Comment: `The problem is when I have multiple threads sending data at the same time it seems to scramble things and stop working. Any tips on how I can achieve this?` are you using locks? That's the standard way to fix race conditions with multithreaded code.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding `If there's a way of doing that - please stop reading and tell me how!`.
There's a way of doing it, assuming you are on Linux or using WSL on Windows, you could use the `hostname -I` commend which will output an IP that looks like `192.168.X.X`.
You can use that IP in your python program by binding your server to that IP instead of `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.